# Roots of the system of quadratic equations

Tags: quadratic-forms, algebraic-equations

For a set of $m$ positive semi-definite $d\times d$ matrices $Q_j$  I have the following system of equations over column-vector $\vec{x}$:
$$
q_j = \vec{x}^T Q_j \vec{x}, \quad j=1,\dots,m
$$
with some known non-negative $q_j$.

1. Are there effective numerical solvers for this type of systems?
2. For a given solution $\vec{y}$ there also exists the solution $-\vec{y}$. Is there a way to prove that there are no other solutions exists for the specific problem?

Comment: Picture the problem in the plane: you have two ellipses, so you expect 4 points of intersection. I don't think that you will often find only two solutions.

Comment: uniqueness question is basically the same as asking: $u^TQ_jv=0$ for all j yields either $u=0$ or $v=0$? This would translate into m linear equation in the space of d by d matrices.

Comment: Gurobi, with no (or constant) objective function, can be used to numerically find a solution, or determine that i is infeasible (no solution exists). Other more general non-cxonvex optimization solvers, such as BARON, can also be used.

Comment: @SinaBaghal I can't really see the way one can map the uniqueness condition onto this set of equations. Can you explain it a bit or give some references?

Comment: @BenMcKay That's a good point but I still need a reliable way of checking this for a given set of $Q_j$

Comment: @SinaBaghal I guess I can see now how this is equivalent to the uniqueness question. However, this still does not look like a system of linear equations. Since both $u$ and $v$ are unknown, it looks like a quadratic form again.